# Como alinhar números à esquerda usando str.format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatação

Estou estudando sobre formatação de strings e não estou conseguindo obter o mesmo comportamento de alinhamento à esquerda com o sinal de menos (`-`) utilizando a função `format`. Qual a forma correta de fazer isso usando `format`?

```
>>> for x in range(1, 11):
...     print('%-2d %-3d %-4d %-6d' % (x, x**2, x**3, x**4))
... 
1  1   1    1     
2  4   8    16    
3  9   27   81    
4  16  64   256   
5  25  125  625   
6  36  216  1296  
7  49  343  2401  
8  64  512  4096  
9  81  729  6561  
10 100 1000 10000
```

```
>>> for x in range(1, 11):
...     print('{0:-2d} {1:-3d} {2:-4d} {3:-6d}'.format(x, x**2, x**3, x**4))
... 
 1   1    1      1
 2   4    8     16
 3   9   27     81
 4  16   64    256
 5  25  125    625
 6  36  216   1296
 7  49  343   2401
 8  64  512   4096
 9  81  729   6561
10 100 1000  10000
```

Comment: Vou deixar o link do https://pyformat.info/ caso alguém queira uma "documentação" mais simplificada.

Answer (score 5):

No [método `format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), você deve usar `<` para alinhar à esquerda:

```
for x in range(1, 11):
    print('{0:<2d} {1:<3d} {2:<4d} {3:<6d}'.format(x, x**2, x**3, x**4))
```

Saída:

```
1  1   1    1     
2  4   8    16    
3  9   27   81    
4  16  64   256   
5  25  125  625   
6  36  216  1296  
7  49  343  2401  
8  64  512  4096  
9  81  729  6561  
10 100 1000 10000
```

Mais detalhes sobre os formatos podem ser vistos na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

Aliás, a mesma documentação cita que o `-` é usado para indicar que o sinal só deve ser mostrado caso o número seja negativo (e como todos os números do seu código são positivos, isso não afeta em nada a saída, e ele usa o alinhamento padrão, que para números é à direita).

Isso é diferente do operador `%`, que [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) usa o hífen para alinhar à esquerda.

---

A partir do Python 3.6 você pode usar [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), que também usa o `<` para alinhar à esquerda:

```
for x in range(1, 11):
    print(f'{x:<2d} {x ** 2:<3d} {x ** 3:<4d} {x ** 4:<6d}')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta e pelas fontes de documentação!!!!

Comment: @GustavoAbreu Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema.